# Change div content using PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm creating a movie database website. What I'm trying to achieve is that when a user clicks on one of the movies in the Latest movies collection (shown in the picture) the main movie banner (currently displaying "Transformers", show in the picture) will update and display the selected movie's title and poster, using PHP.

[Picture showing the Main Movie and Latest Movie](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2QyDf.png)

Main movie code:

```
<!-- SPECIAL MOVIE SECTION -->
    <div class="section">
        <div class="hero-slide-item">
            <img src="./images/transformer-banner.jpg" alt="">
            <div class="overlay"></div>
            <div class="hero-slide-item-content">
                <div class="item-content-wraper">
                    <div class="item-content-title">
                        Transformer
                    </div>
                    <div class="movie-infos">
                        <div class="movie-info">
                            <i class="bx bxs-star"></i>
                            <span>9.5</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="movie-info">
                            <i class="bx bxs-time"></i>
                            <span>120 mins</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="movie-info">
                            <span>HD</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="movie-info">
                            <span>16+</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="item-content-description">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas, possimus eius. Deserunt non odit, cum vero reprehenderit laudantium odio vitae autem quam, incidunt molestias ratione mollitia accusantium, facere ab suscipit.
                    </div>
                    <div class="item-action">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-hover">
                            <i class="bx bxs-right-arrow"></i>
                            <span>Watch now</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END SPECIAL MOVIE SECTION -->
```

Latest movie code:

```
<!-- MOVIE ITEM -->
                <a href="#" class="movie-item">
                    <img src="<?php echo $row ["PosterLink"]; ?>" alt="">
                    <div class="movie-item-content">
                        <div class="movie-item-title">
                            <?php echo $row ["Title"]?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="movie-infos">
                            <div class="movie-info">
                                <i class="bx bxs-star"></i>
                                <span><?php echo $rating?></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="movie-info">
                                <i class="bx bxs-time"></i>
                                <span><?php echo $runTime?></span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="movie-info">
                                <span>Director: <?php echo $director?></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </a>
                <!-- END MOVIE ITEM -->
```

Comment: Hi you need to use AJAX technology. Use axios library for asynchronous request.
You will need to add a Javascript - Click event and then send an async request to the server. Get server response and insert new data with JS

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use only PHP, then you can  pass some parameter to server when a user clicks on any movies in latest movie section so,
add some unique query parameter in anchor tag where user will be redirected when he clicks on a movie.

```
            <a href="<?php echo YOUR_SERVER_URL."?movie_id=".$row['movie_id']; ?>" class="movie-item"> <your code> </a>
```

then on server side get movie_id using $_GET['movie_id'] and fetch data of that movie,

then you need to make SPECIAL MOVIE SECTION also dynamic,
store movie data in any variable and use that variable in rendering SPECIAL MOVIE SECTION.

Let me know if you don't understand anything.